# How to use libraries within a java file

Tags: java

I have downloaded a library which contains some methods within some classes that I would like to use.

The library I have downloaded is the apache common lang package and I have the "commons-lang3.jar" file, I am trying to set a classpath using the environment variables in windows 7 but it doesn't do anything.

Can someone check if I am doing this right:

---

**User variables for Me:**

Variable: PATH,

Value: C:\Users\Me\Documents\JavaLib\commons-lang3.jar,

JavaLib is a file I have created which contains commons-lang3.jar on its own.

---

Java file name: Myclass.java

command typed into cmd: `javac Myclass.java`

Error returned: `error: package org.apache.commons.lang3 does not exist`

Myclass.java contains:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
```

and it can't find it even though I have put it into my environment variables.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: See, for example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment variable to use is `classpath`. Also, setting the `classpath` beyond your application's lifecycle isn't recommended especially when there are multiple apps running with different versions of the same library. Just specify the library location in the `-classpath` option to the `java` and `javac` commands. Or atleast set it in a batch/shell script file that will set the variable, open the application and unset implicitly upon termination.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have another problem: when I type "java Myclass" it returns the error: "Error: Could not find or load main class Myclass". What is wrong here?

Comment: do you have this class inside some package? if so, read this post on [how-can-i-compile-classes-in-packages-to-execute-them-later-with-java-program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4910964/how-can-i-compile-classes-in-packages-to-execute-them-later-with-java-program)

Comment: No this class is just on it's own. It is just a simple Application.

Comment: OK, go ahead and paste your source code. Can't guess much as to what's going on.

Comment: There shouldn't be a problem with the source code since it compiles correctly, is that correct?

Comment: The reason I ask is, people sometimes mess up the `main` method's signature. Missing a few keywords like static or returning non-`void` could cause Java to throw this error. Anyway, it's worth taking a look at this answer [error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class#answer-7485781](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485670/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class#answer-7485781)

Comment: I can't fit the source code into a comment and I am only allowed to post once every 90 minutes, I have read that post previously but I can't see a fix.